# Parse.com Stripe Integration - Obtaining credit card token

Tags: parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

I'm currently building a mobile application using Ionic framework, with Parse as a back end. I'm now looking into creating a Stripe customer via Parse's Cloud Code for subscriptions, and i've found the [brief documentation on Parse's site](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-modules-charging-a-credit-card).

For obtaining the Credit Card Token, the docs refer to using the Stripe's REST API docs, but I would've assumed parse's Stripe integration would provide a method to perform this.

How can I obtain a token? Thank you.

Comment: The token should be obtained client side with either Stripe.js or Stripe Checkout